# Preserve white-space when applying str in clojure

Tags: string, clojure

I'm trying to reduce a vec like `[\space \space \space \a \space]` to

```
"   a "
```

However, I'm getting:

```
Clojure> (apply str [\space \space \space \a])
         " a "
```

It seems str is stripping multiple \space chars. Is there a way to get around this?

(By the way, I'm just using [Try Clojure](http://tryclj.com) to try and work through [4clojure](https://www.4clojure.com/))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think its tryclj issue, not clojure. 
Just tested on clojure 1.2

```
(apply str [\space \space \space \a]) => "   a"
```

**UPD:**
I'm almost sure that is tryclj markup issue. Just tested on tryclj

```
(= (apply str [\space \space \a]) " a") => false
(= (apply str [\space \space \a]) "  a") => true
```

Comment: +1 from a Clojure 1.2.1 user. Don't know if the behavior has changed in 1.3.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a clojure issue, just an HTML issue: If I write:

```
a      b       c
```

That renders as just a      b       c because HTML collapses whitespace (feel free to check the source of this question - I really wrote lots of spaces in both instances). Your repl is in an HTML environment, so I wouldn't be too surprised to learn that in one or two places it isn't careful enough about escaping `<code>` blocks.